# How to associate a model with a model within a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, notifications, conditional-statements

When a user likes a comment `create_notification` is triggered in **commet_like.rb**:

```
class CommentLike < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :comment }
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :liked_comment, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :comment_id

private

  def create_notification
    notifications.create(
      comment_like: self,
      comment:      comment,
      user:         comment.user,      
      read:         false
    )
  end
end
```

I'm trying to get something like this to work in the **notifications index**:

```
  <% if notification.comment_like_id %>
    <% if notification.goal_id %>
        liked <%= link_to "your comment", notification_goal_path(notification, notification.goal_id) %>
    <% elsif notification.habit_id %>
        liked <%= link_to "your comment", notification_habit_path(notification, notification.habit_id) %>
    <% elsif notification.quantified_id %>
        liked <%= link_to "your comment", notification_quantified_path(notification, notification.quantified_id) %>
    <% elsif notification.valuation_id %>
        liked <%= link_to "your comment", notification_valuation_path(notification, notification.valuation_id) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

but the problem is that each of those conditionals are nil for comment_like therefore the notification is showing up blank.

As you can see here though CommentLike is associated with Comment, which in this example gives `comment_id: 1` and `comment_id: 1` has `valuation_id: 1`.

```
[1] CommentLike.find(1)
 id: 1,
 user_id: 1,
 comment_id: 1,
[2] Comment.find(1)
 id: 1,
 content: "test",
 goal_id: nil,
 habit_id: nil,
 valuation_id: 1,
 quantified_id: nil,
 commentable_id: nil,
 commentable_type: nil,
 user_id: 1,
 likes: 1>
```

How can we use this association to make the right conditional show up under `comment_like_id` according to comment's association with the 4 other models?

**notifications_controller**

```
  def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.update_attribute(:read, true) 
    end
  end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comment_likes   
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :quantified
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :user

private

  def create_notification
    author = 
      if goal
        goal.user
      elsif habit
       habit.user
      elsif quantified
        quantified.user
      elsif valuation
        valuation.user
      end
    notifications.create(
      comment:      self,
      habit:        habit,
      quantified:   quantified,
      goal:         goal,
      valuation:    valuation,
      user:         author,      
      read:         false
    )
  end
end
```

Please let me know if you need further explanation or code :-]

Comment: How come the comment is associated to all the other models instead of through commentable (which it looks like you have the fields for that but not the association)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here was to use `after_save :create_notification` instead of `after_create :create_notification` and to also add the line `likes: likes,` to `notifications.create(`. After save works better because in the comment controller

I have this:

```
  def like
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
      @comment.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Too many likes'
    end  
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, since I don't really know what habit, quantified, etc are, but your code makes it look like they are things that could be commented on, therefore it seems like you should be using a polymorphic association.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :notifications
  after_create :notify_user

  def notify_user
    self.notifications.create user: commentable.user
  end
end

class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :commentable, to: :comment
end
```

Here, by using the polymorphic relationship, we simplify everything quite a bit. Further, you can use the polymorphic route helper

```
<%= link_to "your comment", polymorphic_url(notification, commentable) %>
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction

Comment: Sorry thats not exactly answering the question. Comments are polymorphic. This is more about CommentLikes by using the polypmorphic comments to figure out the id of valuation, habit, goal, or quantified for CommentLikes

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your comment like model

Comment: Sorry DVG I added the full model above :)